# Can anyone tell me why my DFS algorithm isn't returning the shortest path? (Python)

Tags: python, graph-theory, depth-first-search, shortest-path, path-finding

Basically exactly what the title says. I have a DFS algorithm that seems to work ok at first glance but, while it does return a path, it doesn't return the shortest path and I am not sure what is wrong unfortunately. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

```
def shortestPathDFSNoRecursion( start, end ):
    path = []

    stack = []
    stack.append( start )

    best_path = None
    best_length = math.inf # a big number

    while stack:
        current_position = stack.pop()

        if current_position == end:
            if len(path) < best_length:
                best_length = len(path)
                best_path = path

        if current_position.y < 0 or \
           current_position.x < 0 or \
           current_position.y >= len(maze) or \
           current_position.x >= len( maze[ current_position.y ] ):
            continue

        if not maze[ current_position.y ][ current_position.x ] == " " or current_position in path:
            continue

        path.append( current_position )

        for direction in DIRECTIONS.values():  # up, down, right, left
            stack.append( Vec2( current_position.x + direction.x, current_position.y + direction.y ) )

    return best_path
```

Comment: This is not a DFS, this is a BFS.  Fortunately, that's what you want for this task.  Have you done debug printing to see what happens?  Let's say there are four possibles from your first position.  You push those four possibles, then you go through them all in order.  At EACH step, you append the position to `path`.  Thus, `path` will have every spot you've ever checked, not just the "current" path.

Comment: To track the path, what you need to do is append a copy of the current path to your stack information, so when you check a new position, you have the actual path that led to that cell.

Comment: Well, that is unfortunate. This is actually an educational project where my intention is to implement DFS with recursion, then without recursion, and then BFS with and without recursion. I suppose it does help get me closer to my goal but it definitely wasn't my intention. lol Anyway, thank you for the help!

Comment: A DFS is not a good choice for this kind of problem.  You waste huge amounts of time following paths that cannot possibly be the answer.  What you have here is essentially Dijkstra's algorithm, which is the right choice.

Answer (score 1):

You append to `path` every time you visit a node, but it doesn't get reset when you backtrack because you reached a dead end.

There's more than one approach to dealing with this, but the simplest is simply to have your stack store a tuple or structure that contains a position to visit *and* the path used to get there.

And as Tim Roberts says, what you've written isn't DFS, it's BFS. One nice thing about that is that it makes your "best_length" check completely superfluous. BFS checks paths in order of their length, so the very first path you find that reaches the target will be a shortest path.